# Prove that $x \in B - {\bigcap_{j \in J} A_j}$ is equivalent to $x \in \bigcup_{j \in J} B-{A_j} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that $x \in B -\{ \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j\}$ is equivalent to $x \in \bigcup_{j \in J} B-\{A_j\} $.
The first statement can be written as $x \in B$ and $x \notin\bigcap_{j \in J} A_j$ I thought what one can maybe use is deMorgan's theorem and write this as: $\neg (x\notin B$ or $x\in \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j)$
I am not sure if this is correct and if how to proceed. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Just a heads up that set differences are backslashes $\setminus$ and not forward slashes $/$

Comment: Thanks for the indication. I'll correct it when I'm at the computer again.

Comment: @Lorago I tried using the backslash, but because of LaTex it doesn't look good. So I just the $-\{\}$ to indicate the set difference.

Comment: You can work it out by double inclusion. Sometimes its simpler not to work on set operations but just to go back to definitions (especially for fundamental identities such as this one).

Comment: @Zag Thank you for your suggestion. I don't understand however what a double inclusion means. could you please elaborate

Comment: @Zag Ok I think of kind of intuitively understand why this is true. So because the union over j of the set B without $A_j$ excludes the intersection of all the $A_j$'s since that is always excluded in every set difference and because the complement of the intersection is included multiple times.

Comment: Showing that two set $X$ and $Y$ are equal by double inclusion means taking $x \in X$ and show that $x \in Y$ and then the converse, to take $y \in Y$ and show that $y \in X$.

Comment: @Zag ok. Yes I have heard of this method, but somehow it didn't occur to me. thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It is a very standard method that is very usefull to have in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in B\setminus\bigcup_jA_j$. Then we have $x\in B$ and there exists $j$ such that $x\not\in A_j$, otherwise we would have $x\in\bigcap_jA_j$. This means that $x\in B\setminus A_j\subseteq \bigcup_jB\setminus A_j$, so $B\setminus\bigcup_jA_j\subseteq\bigcup_jB\setminus A_j$.

Now, let $x\in\bigcup_jB\setminus A_j$. Then there exists $j$ such that $x\in B\setminus A_j$, so $x\in B$ and $x\not\in A_j$. This gives $x\not\in\bigcap_jA_j$ and hence $x\in B\setminus\bigcap_jA_j$, so $\bigcup_jB\setminus A_j\subseteq B\setminus\bigcup_jA_j$ and hence $B\setminus\bigcup_jA_j=\bigcup_jB\setminus A_j$.

Comment: wow really nice. thanks!